# Who uses idiom the most?

Tags: idioms

I cant find any resources about the user of idiom, what kind of people that use idiom the most? and in what range of age?

Is there any research about that?

Comment: People who speak.   Or write.  Or draw.

Comment: This is an interesting question, though presented in a fairly bald way.  Let's leave it open.  If we must close it, I recommend migration to Linguistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper titled ["A Corpus-Based Study of Idioms
in Academic Speech"](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/90255/3588398.pdf?sequence=1) (Rita Simpson and Dushyanthi Mendis,
TESOL Quarterly Vol. 37, No. 3 (Autumn, 2003), pp. 419-441) is a (randomly selected) example of such research. For further research and background studies, you could explore the works cited in the reference list of that paper.